# What is socket.SOL_TCP

Tags: python, linux, sockets

When I read the Python's api doc there is a api:

```
socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family=0, socktype=0, proto=0, flags=0)
```

The doc does not explain the parameter `proto`, it seems is short of protocol And I see a demo below:

```
socket.getaddrinfo("www.python.org", 80, 0, 0, socket.SOL_TCP)
```

My confuse is that what is the `socket.SOL_TCP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

proto is protocol. there are several protocol supported by morden OS: `UDP`, `TCP`, `SCTP` and so on.

`port` can also be service name (string), like:

```
socket.getaddrinfo("www.python.org", "http", 0, 0, socket.SOL_TCP)
```

in this case, protocol is used to resolve service name.

Comment: does ```http``` is also a protocol? what diff between ```socktype``` and ```proto```?

Comment: nope, here protocol only refer to layer-4 protocol in OSI model. http is layer-7, it is a service.

Comment: socktype is STREAM or PACKET or SEQPACKET. btw tcp is stream, and udp is packet.